# Cursor stuck on 'wait' when I go to previous page

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Is there a method to have the cursor change to 'default' if I have to go back to the previous page? When my login button is clicked, I want to indicate to the user that the next page is loading, so I changed the cursor to 'wait'. However, if I go back to the login page, the 'wait' cursor is apparent instead of 'default'.

login button:

```
<div class = "introLogin" onclick = "waitPointer();"><input class = "introLoginInput" type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Login"></div>
```

js:

```
function waitPointer()
{
    document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
    return true;
}

function defaultPointer()
{
    document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
    window.onload = function(){document.body.style.cursor='default';}
}
```

css:

```
.vIntro .introLogin .introLoginInput
{
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:#000;
    transition: color 0.5s;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Brush Script MT, Brush Script Std, cursive;
    color: white;
}

.vIntro .introLogin .introLoginInput:hover
{
    color: gold !important;
    transition: color 0.5s;
}
```

The cursor changes to 'wait' and 'default' when the page is fully loaded, but if I go back, I run into the issue of the cursor stuck on 'wait'.

Answer (score 0):

To set the cursor to 'wait' until the page is fully loaded then use JavaScript to change the cursor style when the page starts loading and then revert it back to the default style when the page has finished loading.

```
document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
    
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
});
```